# Get file path to image on Azure Asp.Net core server (in controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I know this is probably an easy task, but I have been now trying several approaches without success. I have controller named AuthorizeController.cs. Inside this controller I would like to specify default avatar image for registered users.

I do this way in constructor:

```
  private IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; }
  private byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }

  this.ProfilePicture = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(
    string.Concat(this.WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, @"\Resources\avatar.png"));
```

My image is located inside the same project:

```
MrDashWeb.Server
 - Resources
    - avatar.png
```

On my local machine, when I run it in localhost, everything works fine. However after uploading this into Azure, I am getting an errors in Log Stream:

> If the exception handler is expected to return 404 status responses
> then set AllowStatusCode404Response to true.--->
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
> path 'C:\Resources\avatar.png'.at
> Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath,
> FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions
> options)at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String
> fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share,
> FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)

What I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: 1. Use Path.Combine instead of string.Concat. 2. Make sure the Path and File exist on the server. 3. Make sure the Path is resolved as expected. It shows "C:\Resources\avatar.png" is that correct? That would mean your WebRootPath is "C:" ? Sounds fishy.

Comment: @Fildor are there any guides how I can see my files on Azure? I have been just setting up my first project thou...

Comment: So, you are hosting in Azure. Then there _should_ be a portal page to view the files. Cannot look it up myself at the moment...

Comment: @LG3 You should be able to use something like Kudu or Filezilla to connect to you server to verify if file is there. First of all you should verify if this file is set to be copied to output directory. You can do this by right clicking file in your IDE -> Properties -> Copy to output directory -> should be set to "Copy always".

Comment: It was this one `this.ProfilePicture = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(this.WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", "avatar.png"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create below interface to get the `WebRootPath`. The value of `WebRootPath` should be `D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot`。

**CheckPath():**

```
public string CheckWebRootPath()
{
    string wwwPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    return wwwPath;  
}
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

I also test your code like below, and I think your code is correct.

```
public string CheckFile()
{
   string wwwPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
   var ProfilePicture= System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(
          string.Concat(wwwPath, @"\Resources\avatar.png"));
   return ProfilePicture.Length.ToString();
}
```

#### Suggestion

1. Check the value of WebRootPath, if the value is `C:/`, please recreate a new webapp in azure portal.
2. If your webapp name is testapp, then the webapp url should be

   ```
   https://testapp.azurewebsites.net
   ```

   Then you can check your file via below url

   ```
   https://testapp.scm.azurewebsites.net
   ```

   [image]